# AWS Create Prod environment derived from existing Dev environment configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an existing environment which I used for `Development`, which was setup using the `AWS console`, the Web Interface. I would like to create a new environment based off this configuration for `Production` or `Staging`.

How can I extract or use the `Development` configuration as a template, and manipulate it in order to create a new `Production` environment?

Manually creating the environment as before, would be error prone, also undocumented.

I would prefer to extract the current config using the `AWS CLI` or similiar and then manipulate the config:

1. Rename where applicable
2. Remove irrelevant configurations, such as the default VPC.

My current configuration from what I *recall* consists of:

1. VPC
2. Internet GateWay
3. Private and Public SubnetWorks
4. Routing Rules
5. ACL
6. Security Policies
7. RDS, MariaDB
8. Secure Key Store
9. ELB classic, with a certificate
10. ECS Container Registry - Docker
11. ECS Cluster
12. AutoScale Group
13. EC2 AutoScale Definition
14. CloudWatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) templates are good for replicating the same resources in different regions or accounts.

> You create a template that describes all the AWS resources that you
> want (like Amazon EC2 instances or Amazon RDS DB instances), and AWS
> CloudFormation takes care of provisioning and configuring those
> resources for you.

There is a beta tool, [CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html), that attempts to generate a CloudFormation template from resources that exist in your account.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually managed to use the CloudFormer tool, I found that saving my template to S3 failed failed, but I did mange to save it during the initial display of the template - phew.

Comment: Great! Do you have an error message for the failed S3 write? Its likely a permissions issue, the CloudFormer instance might not have IAM permissions for writing to S3.
How well did CloudFormer work for you? I haven't used it much.

Comment: It worked OK, but I am very new to AWS, so much to learn. It did save me quite a bit of typing... 859 lines of CloudFormation generated for me, which is a great starting point.

Comment: I have an ECS Cluster too, but that was not incorporated; perhaps I missed selecting it; or it is not meant to use in conjunction with the rest. ECS has its own stack file, which one could utilise I presume.

Comment: CloudFormer probably doesn't support ECS yet. CloudFormation does support nested templates - if you have a template for the ECS cluster, you can reference it from the "parent" CloudFormation template. That also helps with decoupling your architecture, making it easier to edit individual components.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a better method of duplicating an entire system. CloudFormer to generate a base template, and then manually editing it to include all your resources. Once you've got the template, then you're good to go. There is a repo of AWS-created CloudFormation templates available at https://aws-quickstart.github.io/index.html - some of these may help. You can string many of them together using a single "parent" template.